# Size of Cartesian product of two infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be infinite sets.

Is it meaningful to say that $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot |B|$? If yes, in what sense we can understand this product relation?

Comment: If $|A|$ is meaningful in the case that $A$ is infinite, where is the problem? What you ask is *literally* the definition of product of cardinals.

Comment: The right-hand side is defined as being the left-hand side. The left-hand side has its own definition in terms of ordinal numbers.